# VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to add data to access database, but its prompting a error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'directory'
>
> /opac/search/form_ac.asp, line 17

asp code of this error is:

```
' title = ChkString(Request.directory("title"))
   description = ChkString(Request.directory("description"))'
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. The error description seems to be pretty clear. Unclear what are you asking for: do you need [Request.QueryString Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx) or [Request.Form Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx)  or something different? Read and follow [mcve], Please [edit] your question and add more info.

Comment: I've created a search engine for journals content in my library. Presently i m using windows 8. before that i was using xp. but when i create application in iis in windows 8 the following error is appearing again and again.

Comment: I just want to add data from html to ms access db with the help of asp. The field of db is ID,title, description, keywords, url, mydate and the table name is all_pages. If possible please give the code for adding data from html.

Comment: Here's a basic summary of how to talk to a database in Classic ASP, there are plenty of other tutorials if you google for them.  This example uses SQL Server but if you're using access the only thing you would need to change would be the connection string.

http://training.fergflor.k12.mo.us/reference/mssql_asp.asp

Comment: As JosefZ said, the error message says exactly what the problem is: the Request object does not have a "directory" property or method. Why are you trying to use the Request object, anyway? It's for getting data from an html form (`Request.Form("fieldname")` or `Request.Querystring("fld")`), not for talking to a database.

Answer (score 0):

As Martha explained in the comments, the ASP Request Object does not have a directory Property. It is used to access Form or Querystring input.

You can find information about it [here, f.i.](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_request.asp).

You say, you had this code working in another environment? Maybe there was a custom class overriding the default Request object. Such an object could have provided a valid "Directory" property.

You could check all included code.